# Change the class of a div when an anchor point is onscreen or visible

Tags: anchor

I just want to change the class of a div when an anchor point (above this div) is visible or onscreen after scrooling

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details in order to get a useful answer, right now we have no context for your question, so we don't know what you're talking about. It sounds like an HTML question: how are you hoping to implement this? CSS? Javascript? Something else? Providing some sample code and a detailed description of what you're trying to accomplish will increase the chances that someone here will help you.

Comment: sorry, I was working with wordpress and I want to display a div when the user arrive at the end of a post, so I put a div with id="end" and  above an anchor #end-of-the-post. I want to add a class to the div #end when #end-of-the-post is on screen, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($el) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
      elemTop = $el.offset().top,
      elemBottom = elemTop + $el.height();
    return ((elemBottom > docViewTop) && (elemTop < docViewBottom) && (elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop > docViewTop));
  }
```

and test if the element is visible.

```
if(test($('.testElement'))){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what to do with this